# Calculating image size before sharing to email

Tags: java, android, imaging

In my application, I need to share JPEG images through email. If the image is too big, need to show a dialog to user to reduce the size with different options with estimated size, like

Actual (Size)

Large (Size)

Medium (Size)

And if user selects one of the options, will compress the image in the selected quality.

Challenge I am facing is to find out the sizes for each quality in advance (before actually compressing the file), as I do not want to compress the file in all qualities.

Currently I am using `Bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat format, int quality, OutputStream stream)` function with different quality levels (60 for Large and 30 for small).

Ay suggestions would be really helpful!

Comment: Not knowing how the compression is done, you could take a few images and try all compression qualities from 0-100 for each. This way you can find the size ratio after compression. Also it probably depends on the starting quality of your image so you'll have to know that too.

Comment: Thanks Nicolas. I tried this option. But it didn't help. It varies based on the type of image, like black & white only or color images. I couldn't find an average which is close to actual size.

Comment: Maybe you can change the image size instead of the quality, it would have a similar effect. The change in size would be linear: 100x100 image with size of 4Ko becomes 1Ko after resize in 50x50.